# How to prevent authorized users to view or modify via links?

Tags: php

I'm wondering how to prevent authorized users from viewing and modifying other users resources.

For example let's say I have a link http://something.com/dashboard/show_data/34. Now, how to prevent me from writing something like http://something.com/dashboard/show_data/75 in browser address bar and view that page even though I'm not authorized to view that resource because it belongs to some other user? The problem is also in code structure because i want to show the list even if it is empty. Unauthorized user can't see data but the page gets displayed anyway. I want that page not displayed if it is accessed by not authorized user.
Query returns null for empty list and unauthorized user both. How to differentiate if it's empty list or unauthorized user?

Do I do this querying certain parameters or in code itself?

Also, I have a function that takes data id (34 and 75) and shows users data.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        Authenticate::handleLogin(); //checks if $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] is set
    }

    public function show_list($list_id)
    {
        if (isset($list_id)) {

            //how to change this code so unauthorized users cant get this rendered view
            $task_model        = $this->loadModel('TaskModel');
            $tasks             = $task_model->showTasks($list_id);
            $this->view->tasks = $tasks;
            $this->view->render('task/task');

        } else {
            header('location:' . URL . 'dashboard/index');
        }
    }
    //in model
    public function showTasks($list_id)
    {
        if (isset($_GET['sort_task']) and !empty($_GET['sort_task'])) {
            $sort_parameter = strip_tags($_GET['sort_task']);
            $sort_order     = $this->sortData($sort_parameter);
            $sort_order     = 't.task' . $sort_order;
        } else {
            $sort_order = 't.task_name';
        }

        $sql = "SELECT t.task_name, t.task_id, t.task_priority, t.task_deadline, t.task_completed, l.list_id
                FROM task AS t
                LEFT JOIN list AS l ON l.list_id = :list_id AND l.list_id = t.list_id
                WHERE l.user_id = :user_id
                ORDER BY $sort_order";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':list_id' => $list_id, ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']));


        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: Well, if a user is authorized or rather authenticated, you know who he is. You can base your decision to show content on that premise.

Comment: Yes but queries get bloated and hard to read (i'd have to do that for every query that has business with data). I'm wondering if there is simpler solution. I can't figure out anything to do it in function code.

Comment: `Bloated` is rather vague. Without information on how you handle authentication and permissions and on which parameters you would determine that a user has access to a specific resource your question is very broad.

Comment: Before serving the response check if the user's ID corresponds with the ID(s) that are authorized to view that particular page, if it doesn't correspond just return a 403 unauthorized error.

Comment: What are 34 and 75 ? List Ids ?

Comment: Yes, sent as parameter from url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, may be I'm wrong, but from what I see, you just need to change your `LEFT JOIN` by an `INNER JOIN`

If 34 and 75 are list IDs, you already verify that this list is related to the user connected :

You have this in your query :

```
WHERE l.user_id = :user_id
```

And then you have :

```
:user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']
```

So, if you change the `JOIN`,  data will output only if the list ID is also related to the user connected...

UPDATE :

Change your `show_list` function to something like this :

```
public function show_list($list_id)
{
    if (isset($list_id)) {

        $sql = "SELECT count(*) as count 
                FROM list
                WHERE user_id = :user_id";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']));

        $row = $query->fetch();

        if ($row['count'] != 0) { //At least one list is related to this user, authorized
            //how to change this code so unauthorized users cant get this rendered view
            $task_model        = $this->loadModel('TaskModel');
            $tasks             = $task_model->showTasks($list_id);
            $this->view->tasks = $tasks;
            $this->view->render('task/task');   
        } else { //No list is related to this user, nonauthorized
            header('location:' . URL . 'dashboard/index');
        }
    } else {
        header('location:' . URL . 'dashboard/index');
    }
}
```

Comment: INNER JOIN outputs correct result but that does not solve the problem because i want to show list even if it is empty.

Comment: So you are supposed to be already OK...no ? May be I suggest to remove the `WHERE`clause and put the `l.user_id = :user_id` at the `JOIN` level

Comment: It's strange cause you are retrieving list data only if the list are related to the connected user....you miss something or you didn't give us all we need to evaluate the situation...

Comment: Correct, everything is ok with query i just don't want that page displayed to unauthorized user. Query returns null for empty list and unauthorized user both. How to differentiate if it's empty list or unauthorized user? I edited the original question so please take a look if time permits.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to check the currently logged in user against a list of users who were authorized to use the requested resource. You would want to run this check right after returning data from the database, but before outputting it to the user.

```
$user = isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : '';    
if(!in_array($user, $authorized_users)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    die("<h1>Sorry $user! You are not approved for accessing this resource.</h1>
    <br>Please contact the webmaster if this is in error<br>");
}
```

I'm not sure how your included code above fits into actually displaying content to the user, but you would use this code snippet to exit the PHP script if the user requesting the resource wasn't in the list of users that were authorized to view it.